# twig - если id = 61 или 71, как написать?

Tags: twig

Не могу написать это условие. Мне нужно выводить товары **если id их категории = 61 или = 71 или и то, и то**

```
{% if product.cat_id == ['61', '71'] %}
```

так не работает. Уже заместо == пробовал in/sameas, ids с ковычками/скобками и без.
Как правильно?

Answer (score 0):

правильно получилось так

```
{% if product.cat_id in [61, 71] %}
```